# <MAC> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, bash

I am new to mysql. 
So after download the server and workbench from mysql.com, I did run "./mysql -u root -p" and whenever I entered the password I saw the error below:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Also, whenever I typed "mysql -u root" as other people recommended I got another error below:

-bash: mysql: command not found

How should I fix these errors?

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I did run "./mysql -u root -p"

At least command executed successfully.

> whenever I typed "mysql -u root"

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

Command didn't execute, because `mysql` is not in your `$PATH` variable in bash.

Try

```
./mysql -u root
```

P.S. If it fails with `Access denied` error, try [reinitializing your mysql server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html).

Comment: I tried what you said, but I got another error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I see. Can you explain how did you configure it initially? How did you set up password? What OS are you running it on? It is probable that user _root_ doesn't exist yet.

Comment: above link is invalid. nothing found.